# Is there a way to copy text from device to computer when debugging in IntelliJ?

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, adb, android-debug

Is there any convenient way to copy text to the computer from an Android app when running the app in debug mode from IntelliJ?

To be clear, I want to add a button in my app that when tapped copies a string from the app, running on a physical device attached by USB, to the clipboard of the computer that's running the app in debug mode in IntelliJ.

Of course I could log the string, but it's a huge JSON string and I am too lazy to select the string and copy it manually from the log output dozens of times per day (and potentially have to remove hundreds of line breaks each time).

When running on an emulator, it's easy because the emulator and host computer can share the same clipboard. Can something similar be achieved when running on a real device?

Comment: Tried this? https://www.howtogeek.com/745838/how-to-sync-your-clipboard-between-windows-and-android/

Comment: @activout.se Thanks for the tip, this looks interesting! Unfortunately I'm not using Windows for development, but it's still an interesting feature that I didn't know existed before.

Comment: So maybe something similar exists for your choice of operating system? :)

Comment: @Magnus Why don't you include the OS you use into your question? "Not Windows" still leaves a lot of choices and clipboards is an OS specific feature, so the answer will also be OS specific.

Answer (score 0):

On you host (*assuming you have `netcat` and `pbcopy` available, if not install them or search for replacements*):

```
adb reverse tcp:1234 tcp:1234
nc -l 1234 | pbcopy
```

then, on your device

```
echo 'hello clipboard' | nc localhost 1234
```

once executed your host's clipboard contains

```
hello clipboard
```

you can do this from your app as well.